# Jump from one part of the page to another?

Tags: reactjs, routes

is there any way to use react-router-dom to jump from one part of the page to another, as opposed to rendering different components?

Meaning all the content on my website is already fully rendered within 5 components (each spanning 100vh) and I'd like to just jump from one part of the page to another.

Comment: What do you mean by jumping to another page ? Do you mean scroll to another component or navigate to that page that renders a component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to navigate to another page without rendering it, you may try to achieve this using browser history API. Use the replaceState method:

```
window.history.replaceState(null, "New Page Title", "/pathname/goes/here")
```